# how to change how the window looks in visual basic

Tags: visual-studio

So basically what I am trying to do is in Visual Studio I am trying to change how the VBS window will look instead of the way that it is now because I have seen it done before where people make the window look cool without having the bar or anything. Thanks hopefully I explained it correctly please let me know if you need further infomation.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A window without a title bar doesn't really look cool. And even if it did, it would suddenly *stop* looking cool the instant that the user tried to move it someplace else on their screen. So I don't recommend doing this.

But if you want to do it anyway, investigate the [`FormBorderStyle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) of your form. You'll see it in the Properties Window at design time. You can pick any of the [available options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx), but if what you're aiming at is an window with no borders, you'll want to select `FormBorderStyle.None`.